# Use AutoMapper for equality testing?

Tags: c#, automapper, equality

Suppose I have a class. For simplicity, let's assume its fields are all strings:

```
public class Book {
    public string Title {get;set;}
    public string Author {get;set;}
}
```

I want to define two books as equal if and only if their corresponding fields have equal values. Furthermore, I want to do it in a way that if I added another string field later, (say Publisher), the equality test would check all fields, including the new one.

I'm wondering if AutoMapper can do that. If not, is there a good way to do it?

Obviously, in the long run, I'm also interested in cases where the fields have other types. But even doing it for strings would be a great start.

Comment: does "equal" to you mean that for strings, letter case counts? Or do you want to case insensitive compares? Some possible answers may be affected by what you want to do there.

Comment: For now, let's say case-sensitive. But in the long run, both ways are interesting questions.

Comment: Simply override `Equals` (and `GetHashCode`).  Make your `Equals` method consider all of the properties you care about.

Comment: @PaulSuart He wants a way to do it automatically so that it doesn't need to be changed if properties are added / removed.

Comment: You can always override it in a way that uses Reflection to iterate over the properties.  I wouldn't advocate what he's seeking to do - will almost certainly lead to unneeded additional complexity.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few libraries that already do this, no need to use AutoMapper.

For example:
[Deep Equal](https://github.com/jamesfoster/DeepEqual)

Also:
[Equality Comparer](https://github.com/Iristyle/EqualityComparer)